# Python Regex to match a specific expression

Tags: python, regex, pycharm, pyzo

I have the following strings:

1. `project_identifier = "CENTRAL PROPERTY DEVELOPMENTS JHB (PTY) LTD (1220681)"`
2. `plan_project_name = "BLP416223852-CENTRAL PROPERTY DEVELOPMENTS JHB (PTY) LTD"`
3. `acnac_Id = "BLP416223852"`
4. `project_sw_id = "1232831"`
   I am using the following regex to match plan_project_name string:
   `pattern = rf"({acnac_Id}|{project_sw_id})(\s*-\s*)({project_name})"` spaces around the hyphen are allowed.
   I obtain the project name by striping the project_identifier string from the right as follows:

```py
project_name = str((projectname.rsplit("(",1)[0]).rstrip())
```

then

```py
match = re.match(pattern,plan_project_name)
```

I am failing to find the match even when using `re.search` method, where am I getting it wrong?please help.

Comment: it would be better to put your code in codeblock, so it could be used to solve problem

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I do get the match

Answer (score 0):

Part which you are missing are parentheses in project_name. You would have to escape them (and everything that could look like regex pattern. This code should work:

```
import re
project_identifier = "CENTRAL PROPERTY DEVELOPMENTS JHB (PTY) LTD (1220681)"
plan_project_name = "BLP416223852-CENTRAL PROPERTY DEVELOPMENTS JHB (PTY) LTD"
acnac_Id = "BLP416223852"
project_sw_id = "1232831" 
#I am using the following regex to match plan_project_name string: 
 
project_name = re.escape(str((project_identifier.rsplit("(",1)[0]).rstrip()))
print(project_name)

pattern = rf"({acnac_Id}|{project_sw_id})(\s*-\s*)({project_name})"
print(pattern)
match = re.match(pattern,plan_project_name)
print(match)
```